# How do I change the default keyring password?

Tags: password, gnome-keyring

When I log in & the `gnome-keyring-daemon` is running, then I'm prompted to unlock all passwords stored in the so called `Default keyring` using some password I've picked before.

How can I change the password I've picked?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since this is one of the highest ranked post on google when searching for how to change the default keyring password I thought I could add an answer for Ubuntu 20.04 for anyone still looking for this.

---

Open "Passwords and Keys"

[image: Open "Passwords and Keys"]

Then right click on the keyring and choose "Change password" and follow the instructions.
[image: right click on the keyring]

Comment: I do not have the app installed in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 19):

I've found the best solution to use the `seahorse` package, which can handle changing the password of the keyring, deleting the keyring, creating new keyring an so on ...

So, if you have some derivative of Ubuntu (like Lubuntu), you should first install `seahorse`:

```
apt install seahorse
```

Launch the `seahorse`, right click your `Default keyring` and choose `Change password`.

You will be prompted for your old password first. Then you have to enter your new password twice & submit.

Done.

Comment: Isn't it installed by default anyway?

Comment: Not in my Lubuntu 17.10

Comment: that's probably something you should mention in the question. It's installed by default in Ubuntu

Comment: That works, great!

Comment: on server ubuntu (on raspberry) + xfce, I installed seahorse but I didn't help me. I removed all files in /home/<user>/.local/share/keyrings and it reset (src: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Resetting_the_keyring)

Comment: Just tried on Ubuntu 20 (LTS) and a GnuPG keys window showed up with a centered message saying "This collection seems to be empty", which indicates there's not even the "Default keyring" there. So this did not work for me.

Comment: I had to install `seahorse` for Mint 21.2. @GuilhermeRossato, look under the Passwords section (not Keys).