# How do I change the "Default keyring" password?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, password, keyrings, kwallet

i am on Kubuntu 22.04 running KDE Plasma 5.24.7.

I have recently changed my Operating System user password, and I also changed my KWallet password.

Since then, when I boot my pc, this popup appears, sayng that

> An application wants access to the keyring "Default keyring"

[image: Popup asking to input password to unlock the "Default keyring"1]

To unlock it I must enter my old kwallet password.

I am very confused:

1. is this popup kwallet? I don't think cause I am totally sure that I successfully changed kwallet password
2. how do I change this "Default keyring" password?

I have found this [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978329/how-do-i-change-the-default-keyring-password) but it's more focused on Gnome. **I would also appreciate a clarification about the relation between kwallet and this keyring.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer by myself, this [thread on an archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252196) put me on the right path.

Essentially the popup I see is "Gnome Keyring", and it's installed and used even on a KDE Plasma installation cause some application relies on it.

So when I changed my KWallet password, the Gnome Keyring password remained unchanged.

The solution was to install [Gnome Seahorse](https://flathub.org/it/apps/org.gnome.seahorse.Application) and with it, change the password of the "Default keyring" and "Login".

I must say that this sounds very complex and outside the scope of an average user.