# Ubuntu Password Manager

Tags: kde, password, keyrings

I have changed by desktop to KDE and purged/removed Gdm3.
However, when I open Skype the ubuntu keyring still pops up and asks for a password. I can't find "passwords and keys" in my applications anymore.

How do I remove this?
I want to use KDEWallet instead, which is what all my other applications use.

Comment: Possibly related: [kubuntu - How do I change the "Default keyring" password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475138/how-do-i-change-the-default-keyring-password)